# Trigger an API call in servicenow On New Incident Created

Tags: api, events, triggers, servicenow

I am trying to trigger an API call with Incident Sys_id as parameter, when an new incident gets created in Service Now.

```
(function executeRule(current, previous /*null when async*/) {

    If(current.operation() == 'insert') ;   {
        //
    }
    // Add your code here

})(current, previous);
```

how can i achieve this ?

My api:

```
https://Demand.jitterbit.cc/defaultUrlPrefix/v1.0/snowSalesforceCaseCreate
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create rest message, and there you can use the method which you want to use(ex: post), and you can add the parameters that you want(ex: sys_id)..

later to that you can create Business Rule, in that business rule call the rest message and pass the parameters